# Simple (return:void) cout function returns memory location c++

Tags: c++, function, header, cout

Hey guys I wrote a very simple program in following a tutorial on header files where I define a function in the header like

```
void SayHello()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
}
```

and then call it in the main.cpp

instead of print hello to the screen it prints a number like

00E51028

which I believe is a memory location???

I am just wondering why this is, and how I can fix it. Thanks guys

edit main.cpp code

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
void SayHello();

std::cout<<SayHello<<std::endl;

std::system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you call it? show the code

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bb678d0580f32a2a6851cdf77b2084ee-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc). Please show the relevant code

Comment: Perhaps you wrote a wide string `L"Hello"` to a narrow stream or vice-versa?

Comment: This is just silly. A) this has nothing to do with C or "headers" and you should fix the tagging, and B) you should learn the very basics of programming (e.g. from a book) before posting.

Answer (score 5):

```
 std::cout<<SayHello<<std::endl;
```

This print the address of function `SayHello`, which is `00E51028` on your system. You should simply call it as follows:

```
 SayHello();
```

You should also move the function declaration of `SayHello` to outside of `main`.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
std::cout << SayHello << std::endl;
```

This isn't printing a string, that's just the name of the function. The function `SayHello` will decay into a function *pointer* and that's why an address is being printed.

Since the function already contains an instruction to print the string, all you need to do is call the function:

```
SayHello(); // prints "Hello" to standard output
```

If the function returned a string you could print out its return value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string SayHello()
{
    return "Hello";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << SayHello() << std::endl; // note the () operator to call the function
                                         // and return its return value to the expression
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Hey guys I wrote a very simple program in following a tutorial on header files where I define a function in the header like"

Header files are for declarations. You define it in the .cpp (or .C etc) file. This file is compiled once to create an object file. The header file tells the compiler that the signature is thus. e